# How to find even odd in MIPS assembly using integer registers

Tags: assembly, mips, division

How can I find whether the input is even or odd in MIPS? I am trying to find out using integer registers, but my program is not working. Here is the code:

```
li $s1,2

div $s0,$s1

mfhi $t0

xor $t1,$t0,$0

beq $t1,0,Even

j Odd
```

But this program shows even odd numbers as even this is because the result is in decimal like 0.3 . How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Hint: to test whether a number is odd or even you just need to look at the least significant bit (bit 0).

Comment: I tried this already by xor and and too but the code is not working

Comment: Would you show your assembler version if I'd tell the correct code in C being `if (a&1) goto Odd;`? (or `if ((a&1)==0) goto even;` )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `and` the number which you want to check with `0x01`.

This is how you use `and` in mips: `and $d, $s, $t`

If the value in target register is 1 then it is odd else even.

Comment: we didn't learn address stuff so is there any other solution.

Comment: I also tried this by and(ing) remainder register with 1 but still getting wrong results

Comment: Thank you all of you for helping me out. Actually this was probably assembler issue. Qt spim sucks. I don't what was that but when restarted Qt spim, both masking and xor methods are owrking